# How to point out a table data based on selection option value

Tags: jquery, select

Based on the selection option value I need to point out a data cell of a table.How to get this? If I have select the value 'three' means it should highlight the third table data cell whis has the value 'My third page'.

**HTML:**

```
<select>
  <option value="one">Page1</option>
  <option value="two">Page2</option>
  <option value="three">Page3</option>
  <option value="four" selected>Page4</option>
</select>

<table>
<tr>
<td>My first page</td>
<td>My Second page</td>
<td>My Third page</td>
<td>My fourth page</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: show us your jquery code that you have tried and not worked.....

Comment: Sorry i have no idea on how to perform this function by using the select option and table data.kindly suggest some solution to get this..@C-link

Comment: could you define **to point out** ?

Comment: **it should take me for the third table data**....what does this means if change event happens you want to hilight the specific cell.

Comment: Yes i need to highlight the specific cell based on selection @Jai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("select").change(function() {

var tableIndex = $("select option:selected").index();
    $("table tr td").removeAttr("style");
 $("table tr td").eq(tableIndex).css("border" , "1px solid red");

});

$("select").trigger("change");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4FYT/5/)

Comment: Hi sudhar i don't want to use show and hide option.By default both my select dropdown and table will be visible.based on selection value i need to highlight the respective data cell @sudhar

Comment: Now i edited. i write simple hightlight function using border please replace the code and test

Comment: i changed in fiddle also

Comment: for intially hightling just trigger the change event like this $("select").trigger("change");

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you need to do internal page navigation.

Change your html like this

```
<select id="page_selector">
  <option value="one">Page1</option>
  <option value="two">Page2</option>
  <option value="three">Page3</option>
  <option value="four" selected>Page4</option>
</select>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="one">My first page</td>
<td id="two">My Second page</td>
<td id="three">My Third page</td>
<td id="four">My fourth page</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and use this jQuery

```
$(function() {
 $('#page_selector').change(function() {
   window.location.hash = $(this).val();
 });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("select").change(function () {
   var tableIndex = $("select option:selected").index();
   $("table tr td").eq(tableIndex).addClass('current').siblings('td').removeClass('current');
}).change();
```

#### [Check this out in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LHpb/)

Comment: @vasufederer fiddle added in the answer.